# How to join all data from the same date?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm creating this website where I'm mapping though some data and I need to place everything that will be released on the same day together. But I don't know how to even think about it. Any idea?

At this moment, the layout is like this:

---

**July 26th**

Name, Price, Website

**July 27th**

Name, Price, Website

**July 27th**

Name, Price, Website

**July 28th**

Name, Price, Website.

---

And I need something like this:

---

**July 26th**

Name, Price, Website

**July 27th**

Name, Price, Website

Name, Price, Website

**July 28th**

Name, Price, Website.

---

See how the 27th are together?

Here's my code:

```
import "./index.scss"
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { useQuery } from 'react-query'
import { getLists } from 'api'
import { RootStateOrAny, useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import moment from 'moment'
import _ from 'lodash'
 
 
function List() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const [result, setResult] =  useState<any>([])
  const { address } = useSelector((state: RootStateOrAny) => state.user)
  const { list, filteredList } = useSelector((state: RootStateOrAny) => state.calendar)
 
  const { isLoading } = useQuery(['get-list'], () => getLists(), {
    enabled: !!address,  
    onSuccess: (data) => {    
      dispatch({ type: "CHANGE_LIST_CALENDAR", payload: data })
    }    
 
  })
 
  useEffect(() =>{
    setResult(_.sortBy(filteredLists, ['listDate']))
  }, [filteredLists])
 
  useEffect(() => {
    setResult(_.sortBy(list, ['List']))
  }, [list])
 
  return (
    <div className="calendar__list">
         <div className="calendar__list__container">
        {!isLoading && result?.map((list:any) => (
          <>
           <div className="calendar__list__date">
             <p>{moment(list.Date).format('MMMM Do, YYYY')}</p>
           </div>
          <div className="calendar__list__content">  
            <div className="calendar__list__info">
            <img src={list.imageUrl} alt={list.name} />  
              <div>
                <h3>{list.name}</h3>
                <p>{moment(list.Date).format('MMMM Do YYYY - h:mm a')}</p>
              </div>
           </div>
         <div className="calendar__list__price">
            <div>           
            <span>{list.price}</span>
           </div>
           <p>PRICE</p>
        </div>
          <div className="calendar__list__social">                
                {list.externalUrl && <a href={list.externalUrl} target='_blank' 
                rel="noreferrer"><button><Globe />Website</button></a>}               
              </div>
          </>
        ))}
    </div>
   
    </div>
   
  )
 
}
 
 
export default List
```

Comment: See [`Array.prototype.group()` on  MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/group), and related: [proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-array-grouping), [utility function (TypeScript)](https://github.com/denoland/deno_std/blob/c6b5366d164f16e5ce62ff9bc4a81b4a8d538251/collections/group_by.ts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a perfect case for a hash map.

I'm not sure what your data model is... but if you have something like

```
const data = [
  {date: "jul 1", d: 1},
  {date: "jul 1", d: 2},
  {date: "jul 2", d: 3},
];
```

```
const hash = data.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  return {...acc, [cur.date]: [...(acc[cur.date]||[]), cur]);
}, {});
```

This will spit out something like

```
{
  "jul 1": [{date: "jul 1", d:1}, {date: "jul 1", d:2}],
  "jul 2": [{date: "jul 2", d:3}],
}
```

Then you can use it like

```
Object.entries(hash).map(([title, objects]) => {
  console.log(title, objects);
});
```

Comment: omg is that even javascript? lol i gotta study more. thanks anyway